# Switching between various implementations using module aliasing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find a natural mechanism to achieve what looks like 'compile-time' switching between various implementations of the same interface (same 'duck-type').

Suppose I have two classes with some factory functions:

```
class Number1(object)
    ...

def fromBytes(byteArray):
    ...

class Number2(object)
    ...

def fromBytes(byteArray):
    ...
```

defined in `Number1.py` and `Number2.py` respectively, which implements the same functionality. I would like to write client code which start with the following `import` statement:

```
import Number
```

where my `Number.py` module is simply a file where the choice of implementation (between say `Number1` and `Number2` is made). I was initially thinking of doing away with `Number.py` and:

```
import Number1 as Number
```

in my client code. However, I would like my choice of implementation to be specified in a single location in my project, rather than replicate that choice across several client modules.

I thought of defining `Number.py` as follows:

```
# choose your implementation here
import Number1
Number = Number1
```

However, this solution forces me to have my client modules start with:

```
from Number import Number
```

which does not look good. I d like to have a simple `import Number`, then call my factory functions as `Number.ZERO` , `Number.fromBytes(...)` for example... What is the pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using wildcard-import may be easiest way to tackle it.

**Number.py:**

```
if use_module_1:
    from Number1 import *
else:
    from Number2 import *
```

In all client code:

```
import Number
# or
from Number import some_name
```

While wildcard import is usually considered a bad practice, that's not a case here, since you actually **want** to pollute `Number` namespace with all elements from `Number1` or `Number2`.

Comment: perfect thank you  !  Will accept answer as soon as I can